# how to properly use while loop in PDO fetchAll

Tags: php, pdo

please be easy on me, i just started learning PDO and still finding my way how to convert my mysqli to PDO.

so i have a function to get the contents from my database

```
function getContent() {
    $db = PDOconn();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3";
    $sql = $db->prepare($sql);
    $row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $row;
}
```

normally when i return `$row` in mysqli, i would define `fetch_assoc()` in my while loop.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $content = $row['content'];
}
```

Now, since `(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` is already declared in my function.

how would i properly create my `while` loop to print the values in PDO?

**[edit]
updated code**

i will be declaring my `while` loop outside of the function. so i need something to return from my function but i dont know what that is..

```
function getContent() {
    $db = PDOconn();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3";
    $sql = $db->prepare($query);
    $row = $sql->execute();

    return $row;
}
```

this is my while loop outside the function.

```
$sql = getContent();

while ($row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $content = $row['content'];
}
```

Comment: Since this ranks high on Google, it is worth noting that it would be easier to comprehend if `$rows` refers to one or more rows, and `$row` refers to a single row. For instance: `foreach($rows as $row)`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With `fetchAll()` **you don't have to use `while`** at all. As this function returns an *array*, you have to use `foreach()` instead:

```
function getContent() {
    $db = PDOconn();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3";
    $sql = $db->prepare($query);
    $sql->execute();
    return $sql->fetchAll();
}

$data = getContent();
foreach($data as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $content = $row['content'];
}
```

Comment: can i assume whenever i use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` i will be using `foreach` now instead of a `while`?

Comment: Nope don't assume that. You can still use while loop easily. Its not a compulsion to use foreach, see the edit

Comment: so in my sample above, you can see the i `returned $row` in the function which includes the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. do i have to declare it again on my `while($row= $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{}` ? sorry if didn't quite understood your explanation well .

Comment: Ok let me explain it better. `fetch()` gets you one row by one, whereas `fetchAll()` grabs all the rows together and assigns them to your object. In your example you used `fetchAll()`, if you want to use this while from my code then you have to remove fhe fetchAll statement, one minute let me update the answer accordingly.

Comment: but what if my `while` loop is outside of the function, how do i return a variable and do the looping and printing outside my function . can you kindly refer to my updated post and see if im doing it correctly.

Comment: although im not sure why `foreach` is being used but this solution worked. thank you for your patience :)

Comment: In order to use a while loop here you will have to loop over the array indexes and use another variable, `foreach` suits more

Comment: I will suggest to use `while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  { //code }`, because `fetchAll()` returns all data as 2D array and stores in a variable, that consume much RAM space while working with large data.
Please correct me if someone knows better on this.

Comment: Any query that returns 'large data' for display is itself a problem