# PHP MySQLi to PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I don't know why my code doesn't return `true`, the while loop works fine, but there's a problem.

```
$PDO_result = $db_PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM nnm_anime INNER JOIN nnm_anime_info ON nnm_anime.a_id = nnm_anime_info.a_id WHERE a_name LIKE '?%' ");
$PDO_result->bindParam(1, $pismenka[$i]);
$PDO_result->execute();
```

Here when I `var_dump()` `$PDO_result` I get one item in array so the following while loop should work:

```
while($row = $PDO_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

but it doesn't.

Working MySQLi:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect_to_db, "SELECT * FROM nnm_anime INNER JOIN nnm_anime_info ON nnm_anime.a_id = nnm_anime_info.a_id WHERE a_name LIKE '$pismenka[$i]%' ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Comment: not duplicate % cant be in Param ...., i have other problem then him

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple solution would be to change `$pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` to `$pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

`fetchAll` returns ALL rows in the requested query, while `fetch` only gets 1 row (the first)

Example:

```
<?php


try {

    $PDO_result = $db_PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM nnm_anime INNER JOIN nnm_anime_info ON nnm_anime.a_id = nnm_anime_info.a_id WHERE a_name LIKE ?");

    //Execute by inserting an array:
    if (!$PDO_result->execute([$pismenka[$i] . "%" ])) { //Added ."%" 
        die('Error!');
    }

    //Fetch rows:
    $rows = $PDO_result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //Go trough each row:
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        //Do something
    }

    //Catch exceptions thrown by PDO
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    print_r($ex);
}
```

Comment: fetch should return 1st row then 2nd then 3rd ..... as is described in PHP.net or not ?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about that, but take a look at this answer, it kind of reminds me of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488364/how-to-properly-use-while-loop-in-pdo-fetchall

But with `fetchAll` you do not have to use while at all, you simply get it all in one associative array but IMO it does the same job, and `fetchAll`is clearer in the context of what you are actually doing

Comment: try putting your code inside `try{ code here } catch(PDOException $ex){ print_r($ex); }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153559/discussion-between-kristian-hareland-and-patrik-horvath).

Comment: Should be `execute([ $pismenka[$i] . "%" ])` since the `%` was in the original query.

Comment: @tadman that is correct, i forgot to update the answer after me and OP had a skype session to figure out the issue. Will update :)